# Deprovisioning User in SF, Must look for all email alerts first (manually)

Tags: email-alert

When we want to deprovision a user in Salseforce, we need to manually search the email alerts the person receives and remove each one individually before being able to deactivate their account. The problem is that we don't know exactly which alerts the person gets.I wanted to see if anyone could point me in the right direction on how to make this process easier. Maybe there's a way to see a list of email alerts a User receives, then based on that remove the alerts and then deactivate the account.

Answer (score 1):

As of recently, you can now "freeze" a user, which locks them out, but does not deactivate them just yet.  This gives you time to look for email alerts, code, etc prior to deactivating them.

See here for more info: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_freeze.htm&language=en_US